# What to do if you're asked to break industry regulations?

Tags: legal, whistle-blowing

The company I work for has to comply with certain regulations regarding the software it uses, one of the terms being that a certain number cannot be higher than 3%. If it is the company can be heavily fined. Regularly this number is at 30%-40% and I am asked to use SQL to cook the books and make it look like it is below 3%.

I don't know what to do, I don't want to do this any more, and the company would not listen if I voice my objections. How can I protect myself against future repercussions?

Comment: Is this still the gem of a company that chains the fire doors shut?  You should check local whistleblower laws to see if you can help cushion yourself while looking for something new.

Comment: @Myles yes, this has managed to be resolved, the padlock has been replaced with a breakglass exit, the other door still cannot be opened, and you still can't get out of the carpark though.

Comment: At this point I strongly suggest looking into whistle-blower protection and getting a lawyer. This could be of help: https://www.gov.uk/whistleblowing

Comment: So is the fine a software license agreement where they are supposed to pay another company or is this a governmental regulatory body that a number is reported to?

Comment: Re the update: Contact a lawyer even more immediately regarding whether you can use that recording. You may do yourself more harm than good. ___This is beyond SE's scope, and you do not want to take any action (or inactions) based upon amateur advice at this point. You NEED an expert. The company already has theirs.___

Comment: "a certain number" ??  what exactly is this number ? "has to comply with certain regulations regarding the software it uses" sorry what law regulates software?

Comment: I will be leaving this business, and another person doing my job will take over the reigns, they can deal with this issue, I am not risking prosecution from the regulator body over this, also to protect myself if they go searching I have changed my username.

Comment: You should consult a lawyer immediately.  Depending on the regulations, in some cases knowing about an infraction could be considered as complicit in the action.

Comment: @JimB I agree, Not only that but if you have ever changed the numbers you could still end up the fall guy.  Doing nothing is not an option here, They will get caught and you are liable to end up in prison as the fall guy.

Comment: @Dansmith They can track your changes in username, and any changes you made back to the computer if they try.

Comment: They can hardly fire/sack you if you refuse to do it, as doing so would almost certainly come under 'unfair dismissal', plus you have information that could incur huge financial costs to the company *and* possibly put them out of business. **You need to consult a lawyer**- they'll tell you what the next step is.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

**Contact a Lawyer immediately.**

You do not have a choice at this point you are stuck in a legal conundrum.  If you change the numbers, and they get caught and you have not proactively protected yourself then you are going to be the one and only fall guy.  If you try to go it alone you can expect to get similar treatment as Chelsea Manning or Edward Snowden (on a smaller scale probably).  If this number represents a health or physical safety danger to civilians you could be held personally liable to boot.  So you NEED a lawyer NOW.  Get a good one and realize that the money you spend on the lawyer is worth 100x its cost.

Find an excuse (even if it is you forgot) to avoid performing the task until after you have talked with a lawyer.  From there you will have to determine your next actions with your lawyer.  Realize that you are probably going to be out of work almost immediately, but better to be out of work and free than out of work in prison.

Answer (score 24):

I would start looking for a new job immediately. If your supervisors are unethical (and potentially criminal?) actors regarding this regulation, they would have no problem acting unethically or illegally toward you.

Do not comply with their request -- you may be held liable for such action. Keep a record of any email, notes, conversations regarding this in order to cover yourself.

You might want to consult a lawyer, or perhaps contact the regulatory agency responsible for this, to inquire about whistleblower status.

While you make your inquiries, you may want to try to stall or avoid their requests as much as practically possible.

*edit based on UPDATE 20/05/15*
I am not a lawyer but I would not think it wise to collect evidence yourself. The knowledge of the conversation and the recording might be helpful to an investigator.

Comment: Some aspects of the business are kept hidden from auditors and my boss knows what he does is against industry policies.

Comment: +1 for the edit: employees in situations as these should *provide* evidence (if acquired legally). Let the lawyer(s) dig for more evidence/dirt.

Answer (score 13):

I'm surprised that this hasn't been mentioned, but if there are rules and fines then there must be some kind of regulator.

You need to contact that regulator - anonymous, at least at first, and ask their advice.

You also need to call ACAS *now* http://www.acas.org.uk

Although the top rated answer is fine (Contact a lawyer), I suspect that may well be easier said than done. Most solicitors are either criminal defence, specialise in something like family law or conveyancing or tend to be corporate focussed. I'm certainly not implying it's impossible, but I think the average "man on the street" will struggle to find a legal expert with the knowledge and inclination to get involved here.

With all that said - I'm presuming whatever it is you're discussing is either criminal or morally outrageous. I'm not saying it's fine, but I certainly wouldn't go full Snowdon over a company breaking some kind of contract with another company. It's certainly indicative of their corporate personality and I'd probably leave, but some scale is needed here and some fights simply aren't yours to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't want to do this anymore

Sounds like you've already done it.  In many locales it's conspiracy to know of a crime but not do anything about it, actually taking part is even worse.

I'd move on ASAP,  but be prepared, as soon as it comes out (and it will, it always does), you'll be pulled back into it even if you are working somewhere else.  Best thing might be to alert the authorities and admit your part, you'll likely get more sympathy from a judge.

Comment: that's the thing I'm not sure if it is "illegal" as it is a civil matter.

Comment: It may not be strictly speaking illegal,  but it it's serious enough that your boss wants to fake the numbers and keep it quiet,  so still trouble when it comes out.

Comment: If there are fines involved, I wouldn't think it is a civil matter.

Comment: Or is this a self-regulating industry where the fine goes to the industry body?

Comment: Not familiar with all the laws in the UK, but generally if a publicly traded company cooks the books to avoid fines, that can be viewed as fraud.

Comment: @cdkMoose - The voilation may have been a fine.  The coverup is almost always criminal, unless the perpetrator is really rich and powerful and has allies in the current administration.

Comment: @Denslat, this is why it is urgent that you consult a lawyer immediately. It is highly likley that anything involving cooking the books is illegal but you need to know for sure whether it is and if so what your options are to avoid prison.  The fact that the bosses don't want to commit anything to paper is a huge red flag; it means they are protecting themselves and you will be the person going to jail when this comes to light. You need legal representation sooner rather than later.

Answer (score -2):

I agree you need to collect data.  You may even go as far as getting a backup of the database.  But that may be stealing.  You need to consult a lawyer.

You don't have a lot of outs:

- Refuse to change the data
  But this will likely get you fired and you have done it before so it provides you with little protection
- Whistle blow
  The problem you have there is it may take you a while to get organized
  So you may be forced to change the data again just to buy time
- Not the best option but maybe give them the SQL command to update the data but tell them you are not willing to perform the command.  I know it is a fine line but technically you did not change the data.  Even this is likely to get you fired and give them a chance to defend (put the blame on you).  It kind of sounds like you are in a position of you need to whistle blow and have the element of surprise.  But this may be an option to stay employed and just not be the one to change the data.

Comment: Getting a backup of the database can never be stealing, in the legal sense of the word. It might be unauthorized access to the data, it might be computer fraud, it might be a violation of copyright (depending on what's in it), or any other of a number of possibilities, but since the original copy still exists (even the original backup), it cannot be theft because theft (or stealing) implies that whoever originally held the object no longer has it. Theft would be if you, without authorization, take possession of the *physical media* the backup is stored on.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Really and if i worked at a credit company and took a backup of credit card numbers I did not steal anything.

Comment: Why would you be stealing anything? In such a situation, you would likely be dealing with data without authorization, could probably be charged with preparation for financial fraud, etc. (as above!), but in the situation you describe, exactly what does the credit card company lose simply because you make a copy of a computer file? *Legally speaking, the term "theft" or "stealing" is very specific.* Again, if you took possession of the physical media, that would be theft, but that's not the same thing *at all* as making a copy of something.

Comment: Suppose you lend me (give me access to) a document. While it is in my possession, I put it in a photocopier and make a copy of it (copy it to a thumb drive of my own), before giving you back the original (telling you I no longer need access to it, and have the access revoked). What exactly have I stolen from you?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling It is not a database in his possession.    Nor was the database given to him.  Data is property.   You don't know the data is not copyrighted or a trade secrete.

Comment: Violation of copyright or dealing inappropriately with company trade secrets is *not* theft. It is violation of copyright or dealing inappropriately with company trade secrets. Which are still crimes, but *not theft*.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I am not buying that. I recommend the OP talk to an attornery.  I know for a fact a person in the US was convicted of theft for taking a copy of a customer list.  I am not seeking legal advice - let it go.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - Actually if you do it on your computer using resources that are all yours then nothing was stolen.  You had possession of the original that would make it legally yours.  If you copy it on his computer knowing you were not allowed to then you stole the use of his computer. If you do it at his place on your laptop(not plugged in or on their wifi)  and were not allowed to leave with the thumb drive then you would not meet the legal definition of ownership, then you stole the data,

Comment: @ReallyTiredOfThisGame How is a database on a company server your possession?  Network rights to a backup file does not make it in my possession.

Comment: @Blam - Exactly you have no way of legally taking possession of that db unless it is given to you by someone with the authority to do so

Comment: Getting fired would put the company in the light, and would likely provoke retaliation from the OP. No, I don't think they would be fired.